# PostgreSQL Can I create users with password expired?

Tags: postgresql, authentication, postgresql-9.1

I create users or roles with login, but when the user login for the first time in the database, (pgadmin) doesnt ask to change the password.

I need use password expired in the first login, is it posible?

Comment: Are you really still using Postgres 9.1? Then you should plan your upgrade now. Postgres 9.1 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL has no provision for forcing a password change, neither by timeout nor by any other means.

The best you can do is to set a `VALID UNTIL` on the user and write them an e-mail that they should change the password before the user expires. As soon as they report back, you can remove the `VALID UNTIL`.

Comment: Sure, but the user can't write the new password.
In this case, only me write the password.

Comment: The user can change its own password. Perhaps I misunderstand you. What do you mean by "only you write the password"?

Comment: Sorry, I am a DBA. I think and write the users password. With "valid until" the user was lock

Comment: I mean: You set an initial password and an expiry date. You notify the user. The user changes the password and notifies you. Then you remove the expiry date.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the password to expire as soon as the role is created.

```
create role testrole2 password 'test' valid until '2019-11-11 15:23:00.533249+00';
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createrole.html

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't allow the user to change the password; it unconditionally locks the user out.